# nginx url no longer exists and needs redirection

Tags: nginx

I have an application which was using a url in the format:

http://www.example.com/something/handle/uniquecode

This url has been changed to

http://www.example.com/s/h/uniquecode

and I would like to allow people with the old url still access to the system. How can I write this redirect in nginx?

PS: Currently if someone tries to access http://www.example.com/something/handle/uniquecode will receive a 404 page

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite check if this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, this can be easily achieved by adding this nginx configuration file:

```
rewrite ^/something/handle/(.*) /s/h/$1 permanent;
```